# how can I create a list of string where only the last element is different

Tags: python, list

how can I create a list like the one given below using an iterative loop?

```
col_head =['mfcc_delta_1', 'mfcc_delta_2', 'mfcc_delta_3']
```

So far I've been trying this kind of iteration. But this is not correct.

```
['mfcc_delta_{%d}'.format(i) for i in range(0,13)]
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes, I've been trying somethings like this

for i in range(0,13):
    columns_test = ['delta_mfcc_[i]']

since I'm new to programming, I'm struggling.

Comment: What output you want --- is it `delta_mfcc_1` or `mfcc_delta_1`?

Comment: `b = ('mfcc_delta_{} ' * 10).format(*range(1, 11)).split()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do

```
col_head =['mfcc_delta_{}'.format(num) for num in range(13)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **range** method in python to create an int range and then iterate over it to create the required result.

**Example:**

```
#col_head =['mfcc_delta_1', 'mfcc_delta_2', 'mfcc_delta_3'] 
col_head = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    col_head.append('mfcc_delta_{0}'.format(i))

print col_head
```

**Output:**

```
['mfcc_delta_1', 'mfcc_delta_2', 'mfcc_delta_3', 'mfcc_delta_4', 'mfcc_delta_5', 'mfcc_delta_6', 'mfcc_delta_7', 'mfcc_delta_8', 'mfcc_delta_9']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a way , I think you can try :

```
col_head =['mfcc_delta_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 5)]
print(col_head)
```

it will return something like this :

```
['mfcc_delta_1', 'mfcc_delta_2', 'mfcc_delta_3', 'mfcc_delta_4']
```

Answer (score 1):

lets say you want to add 5 elements.

```
col_head = []
for i in range(1, 6):
  col_head.append("mfcc_delta_"+str(i))

print col_head
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this:

```
columns_test = []
for i in range(0,13):
    columns_test.append('delta_mfcc_'+str(i))
```

Hope will be helpful.